# How can I print a custom commerce_invoice field or custom commerce order field in the invoice pdf?

Tags: commerce

In In Drupal 9 commerce_invoice I created a custom field for an invoice number with machine name 'field_numero_de_factura' and every time I generate a new invoice, I can manually enter the invoice number. The invoice number is shown correctly in /admin/commerce/orders/%/invoices . All this is working fine.

However I can't find out how to edit the commerce-invoice.html.twig template to print the value of the field_numero_de_factura in the invoice PDF.

I installed Twig Field Value and tried things like {{ invoice_entity.field_numero_de_factura|field_value }} or {{ content.invoice_entity.field_numero_de_factura|field_value }} in the commerce-invoice.html.twig template but no success.

Optionally it could be a custom order field instead of a custom comerce_invoice field. Any of the solutions would suit me.

Can anyone help me out? I guess more people are struggling with similar matters.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it using `{{ invoice_entity.get('field_numero_de_factura').value }}`.